# ¿Cómo comparar dos Arrays y eliminar información duplicada?

Tags: php, mysql, array

Tengo el siguiente Array que me da como resultado una consulta SQL desde PHP:

```
    Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [id_pa] => 1
            [nombre_pade] => Accidentes cardiovasculares
            [descripcion] => Mejora el daño coronario y el tejido afibrosado del miocardio, mejora la circulación. 
            [hongo1] => CHAMPIÑÓN BLANCO
            [hongo2] => E3
            [hongo3] => SOLATE
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [id_pa] => 2
            [nombre_pade] => Acné y Rosacea
            [descripcion] => Inhibe la proliferación de los queratinocitos de la epidermis, que obstruyen los canales sebáceos de la piel, efecto antibacterial.
            [hongo1] => CHAMPIÑÓN BLANCO
            [hongo2] => REISHI
            [hongo3] => SHIITAKE
        )

)
```

Lo que quiero hacer es no mostrar elementos duplicados, como podran notar el elemento de hongo1 esta en el array 1 y 2.

Estaba buscando información y lo que encontré es usar array_unique, estoy usando en código siguiente:

```
echo('<pre>');
print_r(array_unique($data, SORT_REGULAR));
echo('</pre>');
```

Pero me da el mismo resultado de arriba. Estoy haciendo algo mal seguro.
¿Alguna idea de como resolver esto?

Comment: `array_unique($data,SORT_REGULAR)` genera un array sin duplicados, sí, pero entiendo (porque no lo pones en tu código) que `$data` es el array de dos elementos (que a su vez son los arrays con los que quieres trabajar). Así que realmente quieres obtener UN único array a partir de DOS, no quitar duplicados de uno. En sentido estricto, `$data[0] != $data[1]`, porque no son iguales. También habría que saber, dado que `$data[0]['hongo2']` y `$data[1]['hongo2']`no son iguales, con cuál te quieres quedar, o si generas dos elementos a partir de ahí, y qué índice le pones. ¿Tal vez `'hongo2bis'`?

Answer (score 0):

usa [in_array()](https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.in-array.php)

esto indica si existe el string en el array, recorres con foreach tu array1 y buscas el valor en el array 2, si esta simplemente le das un unset() al valor que estas revisando y listo.